# Wordpress plugin to display new content from other websites

Tags: wordpress

It there such a plugin in wordpress that can take a list of links to arbitrary websites and return/display the newest content, like for example newest published article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want an RSS plugin for this, the best one available seems to be http://www.wprssaggregator.com/

This will let you import RSS feeds from external websites into posts and such.

Comment: What if the website does not offer RSS feed? Is it possible to do if for any website with arbitrary content?

Comment: @Jaka not unless you want to scrape content from their websites manually to put on your own, it's a questionable practice and I doubt you'll find any WordPress tools for doing that.